# Split svn2git in multiple revisions

Tags: git, svn, version-control, svn2git

I'm using svn2git to migrate a svn repo to a git repo.
The svn repo is pretty big. The first thing I tried was:

```
$ mkdir repo
$ cd repo
$ svn2git https://svn/repo/ --revision 1:40000 --username xxx
```

This started well but after some houres I got:

> error: waitpid for git-svn failed: No child processes Could not read
>   response body: SSL error: A TLS packet with unexpected length was
>   received.

Now I want to split my svn2git command in several steps. Like this:

```
$ mkdir repo
$ cd repo
$ svn2git https://svn/repo/ --revision 1:1000 --username xxx
$ svn2git https://svn/repo/ --revision 1000:2000 --username xxx
$ svn2git https://svn/repo/ --revision 2000:3000 --username xxx
...
```

I know it's an ugly way but I see no other option at the moment. Will this give me in the end the same solution as `1:40000` or will it overwrite it? I tried to check with `du -sh repo/` but the size is always different (not always growing) so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

The `svn2git` tool you use is based on `git-svn` and thus suffers from most of the same drawbacks as direct `git-svn` does.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout and you can also tell it to keep empty directories by giving it a commandline option that causes it to put empty `.gitignore` files in the directories to keep them.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` (or the `svn2git` you used) is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: interesting, but not an answer to my question.

Comment: Well, it is the solution to your underlying problem. You will not get such errors and you don't have to wait that many hours, besides the other pros. You said you see no other option, so this is the answer to the implied question whether there is another option and thus can be seen as answer to your question. ;-)